# Use svg image as map layer for mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, svg, mapbox

How do I use SVG image as the base map for mapbox GL JS ?

I know, that OpenLayers and Leaflet provide such opportunity for developers.

**Leaflet:**

```
var svgUrl = 'image.svg',
imageBounds = [[0, 0], [100, 100]];
L.imageOverlay(svgUrl , imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

**OpenLayers:**

```
var svgUrl = 'image.svg',
var imgLayer = new ImageLayer({
    source: new Static({
    url: svgUrl,
    projection: projection,
    imageExtent: extent,
    imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
            image.getImage().src = src;
            image.getImage().width = olExtent.getWidth(extent);
            image.getImage().height = olExtent.getHeight(extent);
        },
    }),
});
map.addLayer(imgLayer);
```

AFAIK, **mapbox GL JS** also can work with image overlays:

```
var svgUrl = 'image.svg',
this.map.addSource("myImageSource", {
    type: "image",
    url: svgUrl,
    coordinates: [
        [-80.425, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 37.936],
        [-80.425, 37.936],
        ],
});

map.addLayer({
    id: "overlay",
    source: "myImageSource",
    type: "raster",
    paint: { "raster-opacity": 0.85 },
});
```

BUT! If I attempt to load svg, I get this error:

> Error: Could not load image because of The source image could not be
> decoded.. Please make sure to use a supported image type such as PNG
> or JPEG. Note that SVGs are not supported.

So, any ideas how to deal with this issue?

Comment: And yes, zoom has to be crisp like in OpenLayers and Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know, Mapbox-gl-js does not support to add SVG as layer([Github Link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3699)), You have to do some workaround using external Libraries/tools like D3 and possible duplicate [Link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214485/is-there-a-mapbox-gl-renderer-that-outputs-svg) and reason why it is throwing error is because SVG has pixel coordinates and gl-js deals with geographical coordinates(Lat/Lng)

Helpful URL:

1. https://blockbuilder.org/enjalot/0d87f32a1ccb9a720d29ba74142ba365
2. https://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/18cb7a77b2d9de597b86
3. https://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/dc1ce756527c072885dc